# Problem with starting Oracle Linux after Migrating form OVM to hyper-v

Tags: oracle-linux, dracut, hyper-v, oracle-vm-server

I am planing to move form OVM to hyper-v, in-order to do the migration, I shutdown OVM (VM is using Oracle Linux 7.2) normally, then exported the appliance from OVM Console, move it to Windows machine then convert it to vhdx file using StarWind V2V Image Converter.
When I start the converted VM and try to use (Oracle Linux Server (3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 with linux) 7.2 everything is working fine without any issue, how ever if I use (Oracle Linux Server (3.8.13-98.7.1.el7uek.x86_64 with unbreakable Enterprise Linux) I got Dracut rescue mode with the following error message (shown in the attached image)
[image]

I searched from some solution regarding this issue like executing `dracut -f`, edit `/etc/fstab` manually (note the file appears fstab.empty creating a file manually did not help at all), check if I can edit `/etc/default/grub` but the file dose not exist either, removing the corrupted kernel using `rpm -e` I got the following error "kernel dose not exit" but if I try to install it using `yum` or `rpm` it failed since the kernel exist, I have tried to fix the LVM using the solution on Redhat [portal](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1282013), but I got the following error message "/run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: no such file or directory" (attaching a screen shot)
[image]
For further troubleshooting I opened "/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt " file and found it contains errors as shown in the screen show below
[image]
I tried to execute the commands bellow but it filed `/bin/sh` no such file or directory

```
mount --bind /proc /mnt/sysimage/proc
mount --bind /dev /mnt/sysimage/dev
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sysimage/sys
chroot /mnt/sysimage
dracut -f 
exit
cd /
sync
telinit 6
```

Comment: It looks like the 3.8.13 UEK initial ramdisk doesn't have the drivers for the (virtualized) disk drivers, so can't see any storage. If booting 3.10.0 does work, force reinstalling 3.8.13 UEK when booted. That should rebuild the initial ramdisk image with the correct drivers.

Comment: Thanks @wurtel, I managed to fix the issue based on your hint, I did use a middle layer in order to do the changes at first I migrated from OVM to virtualbox, then did mac changes and fix any issue I noticed with both kernels (for 3.8.13 UEK I had to fix by reinstalling the missing parts I guess its done vie migration tool), then I migrated from Virtualbox to Hyper-v without any issue.